# Highcharts gives error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'time')

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I am getting the error.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'time')
> at J. (highcharts.js:8:201256)
> at C (highcharts.js:8:2670)
> at J.init (highcharts.js:8:200998)
> at J.getArgs (highcharts.js:8:200703)
> at new J (highcharts.js:8:200634)
> at Object.chart (highcharts.js:8:199843)
> at HighchartsChartComponent.updateOrCreateChart (highcharts-angular.mjs:36:74)

When using highcharts I am getting the error as shown above but I have not used time anywhere. How to remove this error? This is done via angular. I am using MEAN STACK

```
public highcharts = Highcharts;
  public chartOptions!: Options
ngOnInit{
 this.chartOptions = {
          chart: {
            type: 'line',
          },
          title: {
            text: 'Top 5 User Login Activity Chart',
          },

          xAxis: {
            categories: new_data.email,
            title: {
              text: 'Users',
            },
          },
          yAxis: {
            title: {
              text: 'No of User Logins',
            },
          },
          series: [
            {
              type: 'line',
              name: 'No of time Loggedin',
              data: new_data.login,
            },
          ],

        };
}
```

Comment: Hi @themadhatter, It is difficult to say what can cause the problem. Could you reproduce your current stage in some online code editor? You can use this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line as a base to start.

Comment: I replaced the code in my editor with one from stackblitz and still same error is being shown

Comment: Hi @themadhatter, Which Highcharts and Angular versions are you using?

Comment: "highcharts": "^11.2.0",
        "highcharts-angular": "^4.0.0",
These are the versions I am using right now

Comment: I've checked with different scenarios and I'm not able to recreate your error. There needs to be something unique in your environment- could you please update the demo or create a simplified repo on gh with your example?

Comment: Are you loading your data (`new_data.login`) asynchronously? It is possible that HighCharts is trying to render your data before it's loaded. You can also try console logging your data and see if property `time` is missing from anywhere.

Comment: I do not have a property time though

Comment: @themadhatter you said "I replaced the code in my editor with one from stackblitz and still same error is being shown`" could you please share that stackblitz with the error in the question

Comment: Hey so I changed my angular version from 16 to 15 and the error is gone now? I do not know what happened but yeah i am not going to question it.

Comment: can you chack that tha `new_data` is defined and contains the required properties. by using `console.log(new_data);`

Comment: Yeah the data is there. It showed the output as needed by me. This error just exists. I checked a bit more and it seems that this error only appears if the high chart is within a subscribe